# What should I do if my professors don't reply to my email for recommendation letter

Tags: recommendation-letter, email

I'm applying to an undergraduate research program and I'm gathering recommendation letters. I am currently studying at a different university as an exchange student. The applications were not open before I left my home university but I spoke to two of my professors, explained the situation to them and asked for a recommendation letter. They both agreed to write me a recommendation letter and they told me to send an email to them when I needed the letter. So, I sent an email to both of my professors with reminding them who I was and mentioning that I've talked to them about this matter before. It has been almost a week but one of the professors still didn't reply to my email. The other professor first sent me an email saying that I should come to his office to talk about this and then he didn't reply to my following email where I told him that I am not able to come to his office.

What do I do in this type of situation? Should I just write a follow up email to them or should I start looking for other possible recommenders?

Comment: look for someone else or call them

Comment: Keep trying to contact them.  It's possible they've changed their minds about writing you a letter, but if so they should tell you, not ignore you.  More likely they just forgot to reply.

Comment: Bombard them relentlessly, as they have no lives outside of academic responsibility and should in no way have anything else to do with their lives. /sarcasm  *by the way, giant paragraphs are annoying*